# The Olympics are not interested in conic section

Tags: soft-question, contest-math

I'm wondering why Maths Olympiad ignores the topic of conic sections

Conic sections have the potential to raise a huge number of renewable problems with the same level of difficulty as the Geometric Olympiad problems. Despite this, I did not find any mention of conic sections in the books that talk about the Mathematics Olympiad. What is the reason for that?

Although Mathematics Olympiad students are supposed to have learned some things about conic sections through school education, more knowledge can be provided in Olympiad training courses.

Answer (score 2):

Math olympiads are made for high school students, and problems should be comprehensible and solvable using no more than high school mathematics.

As the high school curriculum is not the same throughout the world, there has come to be a kind of consensus on what kind of mathematical knowledge can be assumed.

The International Mathematical Olympiad (IMO) was started amongst Eastern European countries, and so the topics included were somewhat influenced by the high school curricula of those countries at the time, and that influence has stayed on.

National mathematics contests may naturally be more centered around the national high school curricula, but will still be influenced by the topics included in the IMO, and so may assume eg Euclidean geometry and modular arithmetic even if it is not prominently featured in their national curricula.

I suspect few countries have conic sections featured in their high school curricula, and so it has never been included in the IMO. I'm also unsure how easily conic sections lend themselves to making good math contest style problems without being reduced to either pure calculus or algebraic geometry.

More striking, perhaps, is the avoidance of problems that require calculus. I seem to recall this stems from it's origin as an Eastern European contest. Probability theory is also not included as far as I recall, although problems with roots in probability may often be reformulated as a pure maths problem.

Comment: I can understand why calculus is not included in the Olympiad. The main reason is that the problems in calculus would make the mathematical Olympiad too complex. In a way, people who lean towards calculus tend to have a different kind of thinking about Olympian problems. In fact, a lot of people  Around the world they cannot understand calculus even though they are innovators and geniuses in geometry or probability theory

Comment: Conic sections truly have the ability to formulate a huge number of problems that compete with Euclidean geometry problems. I myself have been able to create more than one hundred and twenty problems for conic sections with a formulation that does not exceed three or four lines per problem, and I can continue to invent more. In fact, I think it is better to start paying attention to sections.  Conics Many new properties and theorems will come into existence, as the Olympics also have a role in general culture